# MySQL 4.0.12 Insert where not exists

Tags: mysql, duplicates

I really need some with this MySql, i cant get to work

```
Insert into valiuta(valiut_id,valkod_id,valiut_data,valiut_koef,valiut_val,user,archyvas)
select * from (select 0,'PLN','2015-01-02',10,'2,32271851',null,0) as
tmp  where not exists (select valkod_id,valiut_data from valiuta
where  valkod_id='PLN' and  valiut_data='2015-01-02') LIMIT 1
```

I need some help fast, how insert these values... I am desperate, I have tried everything....

Comment: Insert into valiuta(valiut_id,valkod_id,valiut_data,valiut_koef,valiut_val,user,archyvas) values(0,'PLN','2015.01.02',10,'2,32271851',null,0) ON duplicate key update user=0 i tried also this one, but i get error in SQL syntax...

Comment: What's an actual issue? You should provide more detailed description of your problem and what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I am trying to insert data, if volkod_id and valiut_data already exists, it shouldnt insert anything, i want to avoid duplication of data when inserting into table and i cant find anything that would be okay with the syntax that 4.0.12 is using

Comment: Show us the syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for (INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE)http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html which will insert only if the key is not exist else it will update the data.